# HTML Alignment issue: making rows and columns using div : float tag

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- <div class="stack"> -->

    <!-- Row 1 -->

     <div class="stack">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col" align="center">
              <span style="font-weight: bold;">States of India</span>
           </div>
           <div class="col"></div>
           <div class="col" align="center">
              <span style="font-weight: bold;">United States</span>
           </div>
        </div> <!-- End of div row class -->


        <div class="row">
           <div class="col" align="center">Tamil Nadu</div>
           <div class="col" align="center">Karnataka</div>
           <div class="col" align="center">California</div>
        </div> <!-- End of div row class -->

        <div class="row">
           <div class="col">
              <div id="bloc11" class="donutSize">row 1 - column 1</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
              <div id="bloc12" class="donutSize">row 1 - column 2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
              <div id="bloc13" class="donutSize">row 1 - column 3</div>
           </div>
        </div> <!-- End of div row class -->
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col">
              <div id="bloc21">row 2 - column 1</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
              <div id="bloc22">row 2 - column 2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
              <div id="bloc23">row 2 - column 3</div>
           </div>
        </div><!-- End of div row class -->
     </div><!-- End of div stack class -->
  <!-- </div> -->

  <div class="stack2">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">United States & India</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <div id="skywalk-module" class="ssSize">United States and India are one of the 2 countries in the world. blah blah b</div>
     </div>
  </div><!-- End of div row class -->
</div><!-- End of div stack2 class -->

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.stack .row,
.stack2 .row {
    clear: both
}

.stack .row .col,
.stack2 .row .col {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px groove
}

.stack .row .col {
    width: 33%;
    align-items: center
}

.stack2 .row .col {
    width: 99%;
    align-items: center
}

.donutSize {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
```

[image: Output HTML]

1. Need to align the "States of India" to be entered between "Tamil Nadu" and "Karnataka". Also no need of a border here,  align it to centre, something like "colspan =2" when we use html table's.
2. I want a think line above "States of India", "United States" and "Karnataka".(see image label:need think border line here)

3.I want the last 2 rows , width to be in the same line as the first 4 rows. width is not coming in the same. As you can see last 2 lines are not having same width as first 4 , it has somewhat less width(see image label : align the line straight)

I want to use the DIV tags and don't want to use tables along for my own reason. I am ok with table used along with the div tags. I need div tags for each of my containers e.g.) states of india, united states, tamil nadu, karnataka, etc.

I am not able to solve this. please help.

Here is my code in JSBIN.

http://jsbin.com/fasacu/4/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Have you tried researching CSS properties and practicing with them? Properties like `box-sizing` and `flexbox` and `display: table` come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the suggestion from @Quantastical + some other stack overflow answers.

HTML Code:

```
    <!-- Row 1 -->

     <div class="div-table">
        <div class="div-table-row">
           <div class="div-table-col1" align="center">
              <span style="font-weight: bold;">States of India</span>
           </div>
           <div class="div-table-col" align="center">
              <span style="font-weight: bold;">United States</span>
           </div>
        </div> <!-- End of div row class -->
  </div>

        <div class="div-table">
        <div class="div-table-row">
           <div class="div-table-col3" align="center">Tamil Nadu</div>
           <div class="div-table-col3" align="center">Karnataka</div>
           <div class="div-table-col3" align="center">California</div>
        </div> <!-- End of div row class -->

        <div class="div-table-row">
           <div class="div-table-col3">
              <div id="bloc11" class="donutSize">row 1 - column 1</div>
           </div>
           <div class="div-table-col3">
              <div id="bloc12" class="donutSize">row 1 - column 2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="div-table-col3">
              <div id="bloc13" class="donutSize">row 1 - column 3</div>
           </div>
        </div> <!-- End of div row class -->
        <div class="row">
           <div class="div-table-col3">
              <div id="bloc21">row 2 - column 1</div>
           </div>
           <div class="div-table-col3">
              <div id="bloc22">row 2 - column 2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="div-table-col3">
              <div id="bloc23">row 2 - column 3</div>
           </div>
        </div><!-- End of div row class -->
     </div><!-- End of div table class -->
  <!-- </div> -->

   <div class="div-table">
  <div class="div-table-row">
     <div class="div-table-col2">United States & India</div>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="div-table">
  <div class="div-table-row">
     <div class="div-table-col2">
        <div id="skywalk-module" class="ssSize">United States and India are one of the 2 countries in the world. blah blah b</div>
     </div>
  </div><!-- End of div row class -->
</div><!-- End of div table class -->
```

Css:

```
.div-table{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;                        
  border:1px solid  #666666; 
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}
.div-table-col{
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
  display:table-column;         
  width:200px;         
  border:1px solid  #666666;   
}

.div-table-col3{
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
  display:table-column;         
  width:200px;         
  border:1px solid  #666666;   
}

.div-table-col1{
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
  display:table-column;         
  width:200px;          
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid  #666666;   
}

.div-table-col2{
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
  display:table-column;         
  width:600px;         
  border:0px solid  #666666;   
}
```

Here is the link:
http://jsbin.com/fasacu/15/edit?html,css,output

Comment: i update your code for border and width changes 
http://jsbin.com/jaqiqawora/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using the table element with the cell elements associated with it instead of div tags.
For example, for your table column headings:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">India</th>
      <!--table header cells by default center text both horizontally and vertically.-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the alignment,:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>header</th>
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">text string</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For the border, one could style the table using css. you can add cell-spacing, set border styles differently for the cells and the table itself, etc.

Interesting that you are using divs instead of the table element to organize info.  the table element keeps it all tidy, and instead of every tag beginning with "div", you can identify which elements affect rows (tr), header cells (th), and the data cells (td).
have a good week.

Comment: I want to use the <div>header</div>, <div>header2</div>, but this is not working together with tables. Sorry i cannot accept this answer.

Comment: currently, it is suggested by W3C to move away from using div tags for tables, even with the div tag's convenient flexibility.  The table elements better organize the heading and data cells compared to the "jack of all trades". the issue of using div tags for tables is that you must remember which div tag contains the data for which cell in which row in which column.